# jQuery How do I get the div in this code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I get the div from within this (the last) list item?

Currently I have this, which is just plain ugly...any suggestions on a cleaner selector/ solution?

```
var div = ul.append("<li><div></div></li>").contents("li:last-child")[0].children[0];
```

Thanks!

Comment: BTW: why do you use a DIV within a LI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an array-index returns just the HTMLElement object and so removes a lot of jQuery's useful functionality, so be careful with that.  I would tend to approach it this way:

```
var div = $("<div/>").appendTo($("<li/>").appendTo(ul));
```

From innermost to outermost, this creates a list item, appends it to your list, creates a div, appends it to your new list element, and returns the div, still wrapped in jQuery goodness.  If you like, you can append an array index to get just the HTMLElement:

```
var div = $("<div/>").appendTo($("<li/>").appendTo(ul))[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could go about the adding a bit differently too:

```
var div = $('<div/>'); 
// do whatever you need to do with the div
$('<li/>').appendTo(ul).append(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
var div = ul.append("<li><div></div></li>").contents("li:last-child > div")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
ul.append("<li><div></div></li>").contents("li:last-child > div").get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This, I think:

```
var div = ul.append('<li><div></div></li>').find("li:last div");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 var div = $('<li><div/></li>').appendTo(ul).find('div');
```

Answer (score 0):

just for completeness:

```
var div = $('<div></div>').appendTo($("<li></li>").appendTo(ul));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = ul.append("<li><div></div></li>").find('div').get(0);
```

I think that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is:

```
var div = ul.append("<li><div></div></li>").find("div:last");
```